# XP->Windows7: Slow response network!

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares

I have a network with 3 computers: 2 with Windows 7 and one with Windows XP.

When I access a shared folder from Windows 7 to Windows 7 all is fine, but when I access the same shared folder from **Windows 7 to Windows XP**, I must wait approximate 1 minute to open that folder.

Any tips to improve the access time?

Comment: Are you using simple file sharing?

Answer (score 0):

By far the best suggestion is upgrade from XP to at least Vista.  Vista made some radical changes to shared folders. The other suggestion is to use offline files(CSC).